# How to compare 2 JSON objects containing array using Karate tool

Tags: api, testing, karate

One of the API testing using intuit/karate,

Expected JSON is: `{name: hello,
 config:[{username: abc, password: xyz},{username: qwe, password: tyu}]}`

There is two possibility of an API response.

First possible actual JSON: `{name: hello,
 config:[{username: qwe, password: tyu},{username: abc, password: xyz}]}`

Second possible actual JSON: `{name: hello,
 config:[{username: abc, password: xyz},{username: qwe, password: tyu}]}`

Likewise, the sequence of array element is different in actual response, hence following approach of validation of response throws error randomly.

- And response == < ExpectedResponse >
- And response contains < ExpectedResponse >

Sometimes error is thrown as :
Error : { Actual: response.config[0].abc, Expected: response.config[0].qwe }

Sometimes error is thrown as :
Error : { Actual: response.config[0].qwe, Expected: response.config[0].abc }

Would you please provide exact karate approach of JSON validation in which entire JSON along with ignore the sequence of element in JSON containing array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
* def response1 = {name: 'hello', config:[{username: 'qwe', password: 'tyu'},{username: 'abc', password: 'xyz'}]}
* def response2 = {name: 'hello', config:[{username: 'abc', password: 'xyz'},{username: 'qwe', password: 'tyu'}]}

* def config = [{username: 'qwe', password: 'tyu'},{username: 'abc', password: 'xyz'}]
* match response1 == { name: 'hello', config: '#(config)' }
* match response2 == { name: 'hello', config: '#(^^config)' }
```

Comment: The above answer works if  response API returns is exactly as of response1 or response2.

Comment: @NageshPathrut no. the last line will work for both. did you even read the documentation ?

Comment: config: '#(^^config)' will validation the data of individual element of array as well ? I've to test the  array element exist of not as well as if exist, then it's data matches to one of the expected element of array or not.

Comment: @NageshPathrut yes. try it and see. you can paste the example into a `Scenario` and see it work, even without making any HTTP calls.

Comment: Actually, this validation is in a function and  I'm passing the expected complete JSON to that function. how can achieve this using this technique since I have to take the value for other root level attribute like name here from passed json.

Comment: I've created new question in github : https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/643. Would you please answer ?

Comment: Yes. it is resolved now. this solution works for me. thank you .

Comment: @PeterThomas, If I have to take an extra step and validate the password "xyz" for a username "abc", how can I achieve this when we aren't sure about the order of the objects in the response?
something like this:
from the response, if the object1.username is "abc" then validate if password is "xyz"

Comment: @ChethanSwaroop ask a new question and if you provide a simple, clear example, you will get an answer. I repeat, provide an example of the response, and keep it simple.

Comment: @PeterThomas, Please suggest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984679/how-to-validate-response-object-in-karateapi-when-the-response-is-an-array-of-js

Comment: Please also explain your answer and not only point to the documentation.

Comment: You can leave a documentation link, but the link on itself is not an answer (like you say, answers can get outdated, but also links can disappear).  You should not have to keep track of all your answers and update them, that's community responsibility... but at the moment of posting the answer itself should be good, i.e. contain explanation for people seeking the answer. Hell, I have read many documentation, but still I find a lot of my answers here. But enough of this :-P. Either way: thanks for the great framework.