# How to validate response object in KarateAPI when the response is an array of JSON objects in random order

Tags: json, api, karate

I have the following reponse:

```
{
  "success":[
    {
      "id":"123",
      "value" :"abc"
    },
    {
      "id":"456",
      "value" :"xyz"
    }
}
```

I would want to verify the value is "abc" for the id "123" in my response.

If the order of the JSON objects in my response is assured , I would have valdiated using:

```
* match respone.success[0].value == "abc"
```

But my order of the objects in the response is unknown. How can I check if the value is "abc" for an id "123"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Please refer to the docs where everything is already explained:

```
* def found = $response.success[?(@.id=='123')]
* match found[0] contains { value: 'abc' }
```

A tip, you can refactor the JSON to be easier to manage:

```
* def fun = function(x){ var key = x.id; var res = {}; res[key] = x.value; return res }
* def data = karate.map(response.success, fun)
* match data == [{ '123': 'abc' }, { '456': 'xyz' }]
```

Again, please refer to the docs and other answers: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms